# Extract business hours from Google using only beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-search

**Goal**

Extract the business hours and its closed status from the Google Search results.

Screenshot with the highlighted working hours and closed status ([example URL](https://www.google.com/search?q=veselka%20new%20york%20working%20hours&hl=en&gl=us)):

[image: google knowledge panel restaurant working hours]

Screenshot with the highlighted working in the popup ([example URL](https://www.google.com/search?q=walmart+hours&hl=en)):

[image: working hours when clicking on a row in the knowledge panel]

**Problem**

`soup.find()` with the specific selector returns `None`.

**Description**

I am trying to create a voice-activated AI similar to Google Home or Alexa that I can pair up with something cool. Currently, I'm trying to use data from the Google knowledge panel for specific search queries.

**Code**

```py
def service(self, business):
    url = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}+hours".format(business))

    outputs = []

    if url.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, "lxml")

        # span class below is the class that contains the text that contains the hours shown for that day or just displays closed
        string = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "TLou0b JjSWRd"})
        
        print(string)
        # returns None

    if url.status_code == 404:
        print("Error")
        return "Error 404"
```

How to extract the working hours and the closed status of the business?

*PS. I'm on a Raspberry Pi 4. I don't want to use Selenium and its drivers. But I'm open to suggestions.*

Comment: Not everything is html, before doing such scraping always check the source of the page and the related elements.

Comment: just checked the page source there are actually 15 different instances of the same tag im not very proficient with html but its in page source here is the source code view-source:https://www.google.com/search?q=wallmart+hours&oq=wallmart+hours&aqs=chrome..69i57.4072j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8  and this is the tag <span class="TLou0b JjSWRd">7AM–10PM</span>

Comment: well if it is true that when a request is made that the html may not be there at first then is there an other light weight easy to use web scrapers that are available to python or should i go with another language

Comment: i figured it out it would block you if it detected you were a bot so i just had to put some user client info into the mix and it would serve me the html i needed thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Selector for the business hours: `[data-attrid='kc:/location/location:hours'] table tr`.

`.TLou0b.JjSWRd` is a selector for the Google Answer Box.

[image: google answer box]

From what I understand, you're looking for the business hours from the Google Knowledge Panel.

[image: google knowledge panel]

Code to extract business hours:

```py
hours_wrapper_node = soup.select_one("[data-attrid='kc:/location/location:hours']")

if hours_wrapper_node is None:
    logger.info("Business hours node is not found")
    return

business_hours = {"open_closed_state": "", "hours": []}

business_hours["open_closed_state"] = hours_wrapper_node.select_one(
    ".JjSWRd span span span"
).text.strip()

location_hours_rows_nodes = hours_wrapper_node.select("table tr")
for location_hours_rows_node in location_hours_rows_nodes:
    [day_of_week, hours] = [
        td.text.strip() for td in location_hours_rows_node.select("td")
    ]

    business_hours["hours"].append(
        {"day_of_week": day_of_week, "business_hours": hours}
    )
```

Output:

```
{
    "hours": [
        {"business_hours": "5:30–10PM", "day_of_week": "Wednesday"},
        {"business_hours": "5:30–10PM", "day_of_week": "Thursday"},
        {"business_hours": "5:30–11PM", "day_of_week": "Friday"},
        {"business_hours": "5:30–11PM", "day_of_week": "Saturday"},
        {"business_hours": "5:30–10PM", "day_of_week": "Sunday"},
        {"business_hours": "Closed", "day_of_week": "Monday"},
        {"business_hours": "5:30–10PM", "day_of_week": "Tuesday"},
    ],
    "open_closed_state": "Closed",
}
```

[Demo in online IDE](https://replit.com/@ilyazub/google-extract-business-hours-python).